# Return a Builder whose every relation's model matches a specific condition

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have a Order model and a Transaction model. A order can have one or multiple transactions.

I want those orders whose every transactions status are 'Pending'.

I tried to implement like below:

```
$builder = Order::with('transactions')->latest('id');

if(condition)
{
    $builder->whereHas('transactions', function ($query) {
        $query->where('status', 'Pending');
    });
}
```

This returns those order whose at least one transaction has 'Pending' status.
But I want those orders whose every transactions have status 'Pending'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can do it easily using the opposite way, like:

```
$builder = Order::with('transactions')->latest('id');

if($condition)
{
    $builder = $builder->has('transactions')
        ->whereDoesntHave('transactions', function ($query) {
            $query->where('status','!=', 'Pending');
        });
}

$result = $builder->get();
```

the 'has' method insure that there is transactions, and whereDoesntHave insure that all transactions are in pending state

Answer (score 1):

To find orders whose all of the transactions are marked as pending, you will need count of pending transactions by using conditional aggregation in `withCount` and then check if the total count of transactions is equal to pending count of transactions

```
Order::withCount([
    'transactions',
    'transactions as pending_count' => function ($query) {
        $query->select(DB::raw("sum(case when status = 'pending' then 1 else 0 end)"));
    }
])
->with('transactions')
->havingRaw('transactions_count = pending_count')
->get();
```